# need help to print only access_token in python

Tags: python

```
import requests  
url = "xxxxy/v3/oauth2/token"

payload = {
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "client_id": "xxxxx",
    "client_secret": "xxxxx"
}
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, json=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

and my output is like this

Output: In output we can see access_token, token type and time to expire this key. I want output only the text that is in "access_token".

```json
}
    "tokenInfo": {
        "access_token": "XFGXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "expires_in": 3600,
        "token_type": "Bearer"
    }
}
```

Comment: Do some research on obtaining a value from a nested dictionary.  It’s essentially Python 101.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?

```
# get json response and navigate to access token
json = response.json()
access_token = json["tokenInfo"]["access_token"]
print(access_token)
```